# Updated to Ubuntu 16.10 but it seems that I have 17.04 installed!

Tags: updates, 16.10

I updated Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04 about 2-3 weeks ago and didn't have any issues. but after some daily updates I get startup errors trying to send as 17.04 Zesty... I checked Software & Updates and saw "pre-release updates" is unset. but lsb_release and hostnamectl and os-release shows that I'm in 17.04 development branch! how can I fix this? or if I'm really in a development branch how can I switch back to 16.10... currently my machine is super unstable and every time I boot I get many errors.

some outputs:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="17.04 (Zesty Zapus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)"
VERSION_ID="17.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=zesty
UBUNTU_CODENAME=zesty
```

hostnamectl

```
  Static hostname: hp-pavilion-g6-notebook-pc
  Pretty hostname: HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC
        Icon name: computer-laptop
          Chassis: laptop
       Machine ID: -
          Boot ID: -
 Operating System: Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
           Kernel: Linux 4.8.0-26-generic
     Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Daily updates can't upgrade to a development release. Something else must have happened. And no, you can't 'downgrade'.

Comment: The implication being: Better to backup and install 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: @CelticWarrior besides a bug ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Really not much point in trying to fix something like that on a future realese (unless you just want to get in on the dev action and submit the fix to the daily build).

Gotta get a live cd + USB drive to backup your home folder then install something more stable. I ran into the same bug as you, using the prerelease iso from like a day or 2 before it went live. Everything been ok until today.

Was the 16.10 iso you downloaded the pre realese one?
Because a bug like that shouldn't happen on a full realese like that

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just updated to 16.10 using dist-upgrade and not a pre-downloaded ISO at the first day of release so it shouldn't be a pre-release... but thanks for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with online upgrades to two separate Ubuntu 16.10 AMD64 installations last week. Repos were set from the start to Zesty, along with /etc/issue and /etc/lsb-release.

I updated issue and lsb-release, and corrected the repos `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` but 17.04 is still turning up in pop-up error boxes. However the correct repos should ensure the correct software.

Comment: I fixed that "issue reporting title" problem with changing /etc/os-release. this may help you :)

Comment: I had the same issue on two machine; one was an upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10, the other was a fresh installation. Both x64 , from torrent downloads. The fault must be in the distribution. I fixed it by editing /etc/issue, /etc/lsb-release and /etc/os-release

Comment: by any chance, is the software & updates app broken for you? Also what does `uname -r` spit out ?

Answer (score 0):

@David Knag For some reason I can't login under my usual ID user118684.

I've not had problems with software updates since correcting the repos.

uname -r currently shows

> 4.8.0-34-generic
>   and as far as I remember it showed the expected kernel at the time of the upgrade.

Since correcting those three files and repos I've had no further difficulties.